# Как подключить уже готовую базу данных к Django проекту?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

**Добрый день!**
Вопрос такой: Как подключить готовую базу данных к Django проекту? А если конкретнее, то возможно ли это сделать без написания моделей для уже готовых сущностей и указания связей между ними?

Comment: Использовать Django без моделей нет никакого смысла. Если вам просто лень писать модели вручную, можно их сгенерировать https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/legacy-databases/